# What to do after accepting a job offer?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, job-acceptance

I have about 4 weeks prior to starting the job and I will be travelling. I recently emailed the hiring manager about my job offer acceptance. I have also obtained a confirmation email about the accepted job offer and everything looks good.

Since I would have 4 weeks to starting the job, what are some good ways to stay in touch with the new employer ? Do I need to do any followup at in the 4 week duration ?

Thanks !

Comment: Get a haircut few days before, other than that, nothing.

Comment: A commonly missed out aspect ! :) Thanks ! @solarflare

Answer (score 6):

You've got the job - the "sales phase" is over. The employer probably doesn't need or want any follow up beyond potential on-boarding paperwork - which they'll give you directions for, as needed. There really isn't anything *you* need to do, other than stay attentive if they reach out and ask for anything.

When I switch jobs, I take the time to make sure I'm mentally prepared - do some research or reading if I need to switch technologies or anything. I make sure I've got things ready in terms of personal materials for my desk (photos of the kids or whatever). I go over my master resume and enter a draft section describing the new job, mostly as a placeholder to be updated if or when I need to. And I visit my LinkedIn profile and write drafts of any changes I'll need to make (but don't actually make them until my first day of employment).

Comment: Thank you so much @dwizum. That is a very elaborated response ! I don't really have the "need" to stay in touch, since they have all of my information. They are at the moment, offering to help me out with accommodation and hook me on to one of their employees to get more information about the city I am relocating to.

Answer (score 3):

> Since I would have 4 weeks to starting the job, what are some good
>   ways to stay in touch with the new employer ? Do I need to do any
>   followup at in the 4 week duration ?

There's usually no need for followup.

If travelling, it's probably a good idea to let your new employer know that you won't be around the next 4 weeks, and give them the best way to get in touch with you in case they need to.

Otherwise, just enjoy the time off. Get mentally recharged and ready to hit the ground running in your new job!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the job.    For instance, I'm moving from an IT job into a ministry job.   I accepted a call a couple months ago, and I'm FINALLY moving this weekend.   I have been in contact virtually every weekend since, and have traveled there since to set things up.  But my situation is perhaps different.  I will be assuming leadership of an organization, and will have a fairly high level of visibility.

That may be different from your's depending on the position.   If you're one of 10 guys on a team of people in an IT shop with no direct reports and not a lot of leadership decisions to make?   There probably isn't a lot of followup needed.     But if you are taking a position such as director/ceo, or higher level of leadership, you may want to stay in touch, get updates on how things are going, etc.     Even though you're not being paid, you'd be "on the job" and expected to have some sort of transitionary responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've had lunch with future co-workers. I went on a bike ride once.

Don't be a pest. Don't try to "start working". Enjoy some time off if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Staying in touch is not as important as being available to answer questions or fill out any additional forms that they forgot to tell you about.

Hopefully you still have access to email. And hopefully you have a trusted person that has access to your snail mail and personal papers. HR might want a copy of your degree, your passport, or who knows what.

In any case, be sure to tell your new employer that you will be travelling.